# Vector potential of a partially-known magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, integration, vector-fields

let's consider a three-dimensional space permeated by a known magnetic field $\vec{B}$. Let's consider in this space a topologically spherical surface $\mathcal{S}$ centred in the origin. I put a device inside $\mathcal{S}$ that modifies the magnetic field in an unknown way. The modification is only inside $\mathcal{S}$, and the transition to the outer (known) field is smooth.

Is there any way to compute a vector potential $\vec{A}$ so that outside $\mathcal{S}$ is true that $\nabla \times \vec{A} = \vec{B}$?
In particular, it is possible to compute this $\vec{A}$ on the border $\partial\mathcal{S}$ of the surface $\mathcal{S}$?

My attempts (on the shoulders of questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81405/anti-curl-operator) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/129104/how-to-find-a-vector-potential-inverse-curl))
were based on a Helmholtz decomposition of the field or on Poincare's lemma (the domain is not star-shaped...), but eventually didn't produce a valid answer.

Is this problem solvable?

EDIT: I want to restate differently the question. If I don't know and don't care about the magnetic field inside a surface $\mathcal{S}$ how can I compute a vector potential outside and on the border of $\mathcal{S}$?

Comment: It is not clear what you are attempting. "is true that $\nabla \times \vec A$" does not make any sense (a vector field has no assigned truth value), do you mean "outside $\mathcal S$ it is true that $\vec B = \nabla \times \vec A$"?

Comment: Yes, I forgot a $\vec{B}$, I edited to include the $\vec{B}$